# Using Photoshop smart objects, the layer compositions from the smart object won't show in the host document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As explained in http://bjango.com/articles/photoshopcc2014smartobjects/ it should be possible to have the layer compositions of a smart object be selectable in the host document.

**Somehow, this doesn't work with my document. Any ideas what I might be missing?**

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I had to upgrade my Adobe Photoshop CC to Photoshop CC 2014.